PDU interactions with the RDP
I'm working with CVE-2019-0704 (BlueKeep) and have found myself working with PDU protocols. I understand the surface-level, but I need a deeper understanding of the ways that it interacts with the RDP channels, allowing for code injection. If you can show me some of the math behind it, I'd really appreciate it.
I attempted to work with some of the more in-depth research papers on the RDP and PDU, but none involved Bluekeep or any sort of RCE-style exploits.

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
